# How to get resulting color of sass filter: saturate() on a specific hex color?

Tags: css, ruby, colors, sass, hex

Let's say I have the following code:

```
.foo {
  color: #004454;
  filter:
    saturate(1.50);
}
```

Is there a way inside ruby to get the resulting color hex value of `.foo` ?

The ruby saturate methods in https://github.com/halostatue/color don't change this color at all, for example:

```
Color::RGB.by_hex('004454').adjust_saturation(50).hex
=> "004454"
```

And since this color is already saturated at 100% I can't expect this to work, case in point:

```
Color::RGB.by_hex('004454').adjust_saturation(50).to_hsl
=> HSL [191.43 deg, 100.00%, 16.47%]
```

I guess what I need to do is find away to apply the magic that css filter applies as you can see clearly here in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/djlancejordan/q4zg6k27/20/)

Comment: I don't think there's a way but you could use this gem https://github.com/halostatue/color and do something like `Color::RGB.by_hex('004454').adjust_saturation(0.5)`

Comment: @luisenrike Thanks yeah I had already tried that, it didn't work. See updated question.